# Google oAuth - Can not log out

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to fix this problem but I'm not able to understand what the problem is. I've integrated Google login on my website and everything's working except log out. There are two parts to my website:

```
www.website.com
www.website.com/admin  // admin dashboard
```

In both places I have this code:
In the head section

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

At the end of body tag

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=googleLoad" async defer></script>
```

In scripts.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //logout of google before logging out of site
    $('.log-out').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('log out interrupted');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        loggedOut(href);
    });
});

function googleLoad() {
    console.log('google load exec');
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init();
    });
};

function loggedOut(href){
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function(){
        console.log('User signed out.');
        document.location = href;
    });
};
```

This part is exactly the same in front and back but there are two copies of each, ie wwww.example.com/scripts.js and wwww.example.com/admin/scripts.js. For the front end, there are couple things extra that are for logging the user in
In my HTML file

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="googleSignIn"></div>
```

In scripts.js

```
function googleSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log('google sign in exec');
    var rootDir = $('#pre-nav').data('root');
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', rootDir+'includes/google-login.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.responseText == 1){
            window.location.href = rootDir+'sign-up.php';
        } else if(xhr.responseText == 2) {
            location.reload();
        } else if(xhr.responseText.trim().match("^Entered")){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }else if(xhr.responseText.trim().match("^Something")){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
    // Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
    // console.log(id_token);
}
```

The logout works fine in the front end but not in the admin section. In the admin section I've got this javascript error in the console:
`Uncaught uO {message: "Missing required parameter 'client_id'", stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError↵    at new uO (h…OahSiUblyIZ1xkzd0Qmcnjj6JLA/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1:15"}` and when I click the Logout button I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signOut' of null`

What am I doing wrong?